# SSL syntax - how does it look?

Tags: ssl, https, packets

I've been searching for some time about SSL and I couldn't find any example how packets actually look. For instance, in HTTP there are commands like

```
Accept: text/plain
Cookie: $Version=1; Skin=new;
```

ant so on.

How SSL packets look like without encryption? Are they completely the same? What is the syntax for setting the master key?

Comment: SSL has nothing to do with HTTP. It's a binary format that looks nothing like HTTP. If you really want to see what goes over the wire, you can use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to intercept the ssl data.

Comment: Note that you don't quite "set the master key". You may be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10438199/372643) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10247166/372643). The full reference is of course the [TLS specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4346).

Answer (score 2):

SSL is not intended to be usually read by a human. It's a binary & complex data format.

However, your can see what it looks like using a powerful tool called [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Wireshark allows even to decrypt the SSL traffic if you have the server private key (useful for analyzing and debugging the traffic of your own server). More information [here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL)